# Permission denied issue with super admin in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, permission-denied, user-permissions

When i try to access the following route:

```
route=api/orderquotecart/address
```

It throws the following exception:

> You do not have permission to perform this action. Please contact the
>   administrator of the store to provide you this privilege.

Things i've already tried:

```
 1. Go to the admin menu: System -> Users -> User Groups
 2. Edit the "Top Administrators" group
 3. Be sure to check all the checkboxes for both access and modify
 4. Save
```

I've edited the rights directly from `oc05_user` table, but still can't access the page.

All the checkboxes for the master are checked and still not working :(
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to enable your API here:
[image]